# Is there a operation that checks multiple variables for an output?

Tags: java

To further explain, I want to create a tree of options that checks multiple variables. For example, it checks 3 boolean variables named, `a`, `b` and `c`.

```
(true, true, true) would output a number
(true, true, false) would output another number
(true, false, true) would output another different number
(true, false, false) would output another different new number
etc...
```

Dictionaries, if statements, lists, and switch statements are options but using those it would take exponentially more time to add another variable to check.

So is there an operation that streamlines this?

Comment: How many variables? For 3 variables you have 8 possibilities... but for 32 variables you have 2^32 (4,294,967,296) possible outputs.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do. It's easier to help you if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Please edit your question to improve it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For just those 3 boolean variables:

```
(a ? 4 : 0) | (b ? 2 : 0) | (c ? 1 : 0)
```

To generalize to an array of boolean variables:

```
int result = 0;
for (boolean b : bs) {
  result = (result << 1) | (b ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Note: This only works for boolean array with a length up to 32 (the amount of bits in an integer)

Comment: @codeflush.dev yes, but you could extend it to 64 using a long; or arbitrarily many using a `BitSet`.